# cppFunction in Rcpp error

Tags: r, c++

I used to use Rcpp and RcppArmadillo smoothly till about 3-4 months ago. I tried it again today, and for some reason I keep getting the following error.

```
> blasso_Rcpp <- cppFunction(depends='RcppArmadillo', code ='
+     arma::mat blasso_cpp(arma::mat x)
+     {
+     return(x);
+ 
+     }
+ 
+ 
+ 
+ ')
Error in dyn.load("/var/folders/6h/ckff_c490ml7_lmhj4xqv3lw0000gp/T//RtmpnVptIY/sourcecpp_553970870d16/sourceCpp_3.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/var/folders/6h/ckff_c490ml7_lmhj4xqv3lw0000gp/T//RtmpnVptIY/sourcecpp_553970870d16/sourceCpp_3.so':
  dlopen(/var/folders/6h/ckff_c490ml7_lmhj4xqv3lw0000gp/T//RtmpnVptIY/sourcecpp_553970870d16/sourceCpp_3.so, 6): Symbol not found: ___addtf3
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s_x86_64.1.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
>
```

I don't get the error when I don't use RcppArmadillo.

```
> blasso_Rcpp <- cppFunction(code ='
+     NumericMatrix blasso_cpp(NumericMatrix x)
+     {
+     return(x);
+ 
+     }
+  
+ ')
```

If I save the cpp file separately and source it using sourceCpp, I have the same problem. I have reinstalled Xcode, Rcpp, RcppArmadillo. Here is my session info.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RcppArmadillo_0.6.100.0.0 Rcpp_0.12.1              

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2
```

Any idea why this is happening?

**Edit:** Adding gcc and gfortran information

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix

$ gfortran -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/gfortran/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/5.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14
Configured with: ../gcc-5.1.0/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gfortran --with-gmp=/Users/fx/devel/gcc/deps-static/x86_64 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --build=x86_64-apple-darwin14
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.1.0 (GCC)
```

Here is the error when installing RcppArmadillo from source

```
> install.packages("RcppArmadillo", type = "source")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/src/contrib/RcppArmadillo_0.6.100.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 981341 bytes (958 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 958 KB

* installing *source* package ‘RcppArmadillo’ ...
** package ‘RcppArmadillo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
* checking LAPACK_LIBS: divide-and-conquer complex SVD available via R-supplied LAPACK
** libs
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o RcppArmadillo.so RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2 -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so, 6): Symbol not found: ___addtf3
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s_x86_64.1.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/6h/ckff_c490ml7_lmhj4xqv3lw0000gp/T/Rtmp82GBGH/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("RcppArmadillo", type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Added gcc and gfortran version information in case that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine here:

```
R> Rcpp::cppFunction('arma::mat blasso_cpp(arma::mat x) { return x; }',
+                    depends='RcppArmadillo')
R> blasso_cpp(matrix(1:4,2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
R>
```

Maybe something accidentally trampled over your RcppArmadillo installation.  Maybe reinstall it?

Also, you do not need to assign the result from `cppFunction()` -- the function ot creates is automatically assigned to the same identifier found in the code.

Comment: Reinstalled RcppArmadillo, and am still getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Install from source rather than the tgz from cran?

Comment: Also,  you seem to mixing your system compilers and your add-on compilers.  That may well confuse R.  Did you install R from source?

Comment: I tried installing from source, and did not succeed. I think you are right that R is getting confused with the compilers, however my knowledge on this is very minimal. Any pointers on how I can fix this?

Comment: Sure.  Reinstall R from source with those compilers.  It will then link to the correct libraries.

Comment: Reinstalling R from source, and then reinstalling RcppArmadillo and Rcpp did the trick. Thanks