# Mac: Removing compilers and starting from scratch

Tags: r, xcode, gcc, rcpp, gfortran

I have been coding with Rcpp and RcppArmadillo for the last 3 years. At some point I had installed additional compilers (gcc / gfortran) over the Xcode Command Line tools. Since then I haven't been able to install RcppArmadillo without compiling R from source (and even that doesn't work all the time).

I don't know too much about compilers etc, and try things that I read on the internet and I feel like at this point, I have messed around too much with my directories and compilers and nothing will ever work. Before I resort to a factory reset of my Mac, I was hoping to remove all add-on compilers/ Xcode etc and start from scratch.

How should I go about doing that?

For context, I get this error when I try to load RcppArmadillo

```
> library(RcppArmadillo)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RcppArmadillo’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Users/Dootika/Library/R/3.4/library/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so':
  dlopen(/Users/Dootika/Library/R/3.4/library/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so, 6): Symbol not found: ___addtf3
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s_x86_64.1.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
```

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201837/cppfunction-in-rcpp-error) some years ago and now will every R version update I have to resort to installing from source. There has to be a way to fix this, right?

Comment: Update: My whole problem has been resolved by installing clang4 referenced on [this page](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state of the toolchain for macOS is in a bit of a flux with the *R* 3.4.* line. Changes are afoot in the *R* for macOS build due to the *R* core team opting to bring macOS up-to-speed with other *R* installs in terms of enabling parallelization via OpenMP. In particular, the previous actions of installing: Xcode Commandline Tools and custom gfortran 4.9 binaries have changed.

The new path going forward will be: Install Xcode Commandline Tools, official gfortran 6.1 binaries, and a custom clang binary called `clang4`. The later tools official support the use of OpenMP.

To that end, I've written a quick clang4 installer (in .pkg form) that handles putting in place `clang4` component. This can be found here along with more detailed overviews:

http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had landed on this page first, but for some reason when I tried to install the 6.1 gfortran, the installed said it detected a newer version, even though I had most certainly uninstalled it. Right now, I am working with the Sierra version of gfortran without any problems.